# How to write expect {}.to raise_error when rspec's syntax is configured with only should

Tags: ruby, testing, syntax, rspec

I have this configuration on rspec:

```
config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
  c.syntax = :should
end
```

It makes the `expect {}.to raise_error` invalid, how could I write this error raising test with should syntax?

Comment: Setting `c.syntax = [:should, :expect]` is not an option?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest to use this only if the most-recent RSpec `expect { code() }.to raise_error` syntax is not available to you:

```
lambda { foo( :bad_param ) }.should raise_error
```

or

```
lambda { foo( :bad_param ) }.should raise_error( ArgumentError )
```

Replacing `foo( :bad_param )` with whatever Ruby code you wish to assert fails, and `ArgumentError` with whatever exception class you expect the failure to raise.

Comment: what is `Foo`? could you tell what your code basically doing?

Comment: foo is a generic programming term for anything, in this case a method. So wrap whatever you want to test in a lambda - you could rewrite it as `lambda { my_method_to_test() }.should raise_error...`

Comment: Very strange behaviour, as this way of doing things was supposed to be deprecated - see [RSpec's New Expectation Syntax](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax), paragraph "Unification of Block vs. Value Syntaxes".

Comment: @Gregory Goltsov: Yes it is deprecated, but OP was asking specifically to use older syntax as the `expect` syntax is for some reason blocked on his project. I will clarify that in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In tests where I could use the `expect` syntax, I prefer to define that test in its own `describe` block, put the test content (ie `expect { <this_content> }`) into a [stabby `lambda`](http://blog.dynamicprogrammer.com/2010/09/15/learning-about-the-stabby-lambda-syntax-in-ruby.html), stick it in a new `subject`, and refer to it in an `it` block, like so:

```
describe "some test that raises error" do
  let(:bad_statement) { something_that_raises_an_error }
  subject { -> { bad_statement } }
  it { should raise_error }
end
```

If you wanted, you could also just do away with the `let` statement altogether and put its content directly in the `subject`.